# Customize the distribution of the built files, in angular 8

Tags: angular, webpack, module, lazy-loading, ng-build

what I want to do is separate the modules that I have created in my Angular project from the 'dist' folder when I build. I have tried to use WebPack but the truth could not be achieved, or I have not implemented it well. I've been stuck in this little problem for a while and I don't know what else to do.

I currently have this structure in my angular project.

```
. // <- project
├── ...
├── app
│   ├── ...
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── app1
│   │   |   ├── ...
│   │   |   ├── components
│   │   |   ├── services
│   │   |   ├── shared
│   │   |   ├── app1.module.ts
│   │   ├── app2
│   │   |   ├── ...
│   │   |   ├── components
│   │   |   ├── services
│   │   |   ├── shared
│   │   |   ├── app2.module.ts
│   │   ├── app3
│   │   |   ├── ...
│   │   |   ├── components
│   │   |   ├── services
│   │   |   ├── shared
│   │   |   ├── app3.module.ts
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   ├── app-routing.module.ts
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.scss
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── ...
```

I have the RoutingModule part set up like this.

```
.
.
.
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'App1', loadChildren: './modules/app1/app1.module#App1Module' },
    { path: 'App2', loadChildren: './modules/app1/app2.module#App2Module' },
    { path: 'App3', loadChildren: './modules/app1/app3.module#App3Module' },
    ...
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

what I want is that when I do ... `ng build --prod`.
I want the modules to be generated as follows.

```
. // <- project
├── ...
├── dist
│   ├── app
│   |   ├── assets
│   |   ├── main.js
│   |   ├── polyfills.js
│   |   ├── runtime.js
│   |   ├── style.css
│   |   ├── index.html
│   |   ├── ...
│   ├── moduleApp1
│   |   ├── ...
│   |   ├── module-app1.js
│   ├── moduleApp2
│   |   ├── ...
│   |   ├── module-app2.js
│   ├── moduleApp3
│   |   ├── ...
│   |   ├── module-app3.js
```

How can I do to have this folder structure?.I want someone to help me, please.

Comment: Do you  wand to differenciate es5 and es6 modules?

Comment: I want each module of my project to be in different folders

Comment: Seems to be an intresting use case. I will have to check